# Undefined variable $booking in view (Laravel 5.7)

Tags: php, laravel

So I am working on a simple CRUD.

I organize my form in a separate page view so I can just insert it on my create and edit views.

Here's how my field view:

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"for="room_id">Room</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select name="room_id" class="form-control" id="room_id" required>
                @foreach($rooms as $id => $display)
                    <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ (isset($booking->room_id) && $id === $booking->room_id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $display }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <small class="form-text text-muted">The room number being booked.</small>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"for="user_id">User</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select name="user_id" class="form-control" id="user_id" required>
                @foreach($users as $id => $display)
                    <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ (isset($bookingsUser->user_id) && $id === $bookingsUser->user_id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $display }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <small class="form-text text-muted">The user booking the room.</small>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="start">Start Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input name="start" type="date" class="form-control" required placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" value="{{ $booking->start ?? '' }}"/>
            <small class="form-text text-muted">The start date for the booking.</small>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="start">End Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input name="end" type="date" class="form-control" required placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" value="{{ $booking->end ?? '' }}"/>
            <small class="form-text text-muted">The end date for the booking.</small>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">Paid Options</div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input name="is_paid" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="1" {{ $booking->is_paid ? 'checked' : '' }}/>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="start">Pre-Paid</label>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">If the booking is being pre-paid.</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="notes">Notes</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input name="notes" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notes" value="{{ $booking->notes ?? '' }}"/>
            <small class="form-text text-muted">Any notes for the booking.</small>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now this line gets the attention:

```
  <input name="is_paid" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="1" {{ $booking->is_paid ? 'checked' : '' }}/>
```

When I access my create view it says:

```
Undefined variable: booking (View: /home/vagrant/code/resources/views/bookings/fields.blade.php) (View: /home/vagrant/code/resources/views/bookings/fields.blade.php)
```

Looking at the code the $booking variable is working on other form field items but on this particular item it doesnt.

Any idea what I am missing?

EDIT: Here's the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Booking;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class BookingController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
       //  \DB::table('bookings')->get()->dd();
       $bookings = DB::table('bookings')->get();
       return view('bookings.index')
       ->with('bookings', $bookings);

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        // $users = DB::table('users')->get()->pluck('name', 'id')->dd();
        $users = DB::table('users')->get()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend('none');
        $rooms = DB::table('rooms')->get()->pluck('number', 'id');
        return view('bookings.create')
        ->with('users', $users)
        ->with('rooms', $rooms);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
       //  dd($request->all());
        $id = DB::table('bookings')->insertGetId([
            'room_id' => $request->input('room_id'),
            'start' => $request->input('start'),
            'end' => $request->input('end'),
            'is_reservation' => $request->input('is_reservation', false),
            'is_paid' => $request->input('is_paid', false),
            'notes' => $request->input('notes'),
        ]);
        DB::table('bookings_users')->insert([
            'booking_id' => $id,
            'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),
        ]);
        return redirect()->action('BookingController@index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Booking  $booking
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Booking $booking)
    {
        //
        // dd($booking);
        return view('bookings.show', ['booking' => $booking]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Booking  $booking
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Booking $booking)
    {
        //
        $users = DB::table('users')->get()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend('none');
        $rooms = DB::table('rooms')->get()->pluck('number', 'id');
        $bookingsUser = DB::table('bookings_users')->where('booking_id', $booking->id)->first();
        return view('bookings.edit')
            ->with('bookingsUser', $bookingsUser)
            ->with('users', $users)
            ->with('rooms', $rooms)
            ->with('booking', $booking);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Booking  $booking
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Booking $booking)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Booking  $booking
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Booking $booking)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: what's php version?

Comment: post your controller code

Comment: need to see the controller

Comment: SalmanZafar & NipunTharuksha I updated my question with the controller

Comment: You are passing `$bookings` and trying to use it as `$bookigng` in the view

Comment: Nipun can you tell me w/c view or controller part?

Comment: is your problem ok now or do you need more help

Comment: Nope. it did not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198188/discussion-between-nipun-tharuksha-and-marc-solva).

Comment: Did not work out.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `isset` to check for the ternary operation,

```
{{ isset($booking->is_paid) ? 'checked' : '' }}
```

Comment: I tried this however when I uncheck the option "is_paid" it still check the item field even its not checked when the create view was submitted.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are passing `$bookings` throught the controller and using it as `$booking` in the view. So what you can do is either change the controller variable as `$booking` or change the varibale in the view to `$booking`. As I felt its easy to change the controller variable.

```
 public function index()
{
    //
   //  \DB::table('bookings')->get()->dd();
   $bookings = DB::table('bookings')->get();
   return view('bookings.index')
   ->with('booking', $bookings);

}
```

What I did here is just changed the name of the variable that you pass to view as **`->with('booking',`**

Comment: Still the same error after I change the variable to "booking"

Comment: can you come into chat room

Answer (score 1):

Change the input line for the checkbox to read:

```html
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="is_paid" value="1"
    {{(isset($booking->is_paid)) && $booking->is_paid == 1 ? 'checked ' : ' '}}/>
```

Create, show, and edit should all work.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not passing booking in your create method?
But you are doing it in the edit method.
If they are using the same view then you should pass the booking object from both of those actions or either way you can use isset to avoid php throw an exception.